Why invoking a python program in another python program will make aboriginal program slower?
In my tool hydrotopo, when I run find_edge_nodes to find topological relations for about 100,000 linestrings, it only costs about 10 seconds; but in code below, find_edge_nodes will cost about 30min:
# extract from https://github.com/iHeadWater/torchhydro/blob/dev-gnn/torchhydro/datasets/data_sets.py#L872
import hydrotopo.ig_path as htip

# the same method costs about 30min
graph_lists = htip.find_edge_nodes(node_features, network_features, node_idx, 'up', cutoff)
return graph_lists

In short, when I invoke my tool in other programs, speed of the program will become very slow, and when I pause the program in debug mode, the program will stop in predicates.has_z. There is not too many cycles in my code.
So why will has_z cost so much time, or I should find other solutions?
If you want to know more details, please see this: https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/2108

Update: hydrotopo and torchhydro both use 3.11, and they are all tested in Intellij IDEA with pytest.
I'm sure hydrotopo is compiled (/home/username/.conda/envs/torchhydro1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hydrotopo/__pycache__/ig_path.cpython-311.pyc)

I try to debug test_run_model by pytest, but it crashed with this:
(torchhydro1) username@vm-jupyterhub-server:~/torchhydro$ pytest experiments/train_with_era5land_gnn.py::run_test_model

platform linux -- Python 3.11.9, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /home/username/torchhydro
configfile: setup.cfg
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                            

ImportError while importing test module '/home/username/torchhydro/experiments/train_with_era5land_gnn.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../.conda/envs/torchhydro1/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
experiments/train_with_era5land_gnn.py:14: in <module>
    from torchhydro.configs.config import cmd, default_config_file, update_cfg
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchhydro'

ERROR: found no collectors for /home/username/torchhydro/experiments/train_with_era5land_gnn.py::run_test_model


Are you using the same python version (and environment) on both cases? Are you running the code directly in a terminal (real terminal) or in a IDE (or terminal in a IDE)? Has python compiled the code in the module? Check the inputs (exact same type), with shapely sometime we have surprises and it may use slower structure. -- And probably much more cases which I didn't yet noticed.

Try to run in a normal terminal. PyCharm often sucks on big data on Python Console (introspection bug, other programs also with ipython have not such problems). And "it sucks" in a really bad way. Also if you write incorrect code, it takes minutes before you get the error (and it never executed the code, because it was non-python). Newer version may have solved the problem (but not yet tested, just changelog seems that they rewrote the introspection). -- else no further ideas on my side.

It crashed when I try to debug with pytest directly. I have updated my question.

I know what happened to make my program became slower.
Dependencies to test hydrotopo are numpy==1.26 shapely==2.0.1, the program is normal; however when I use numpy==2.0 shapely==2.0.5, performance became worse.
I have downgraded the two packages and report this to shapely developers.
It has no connections with IDEA or pycharm.
